# Change menu-id colour

Tags: css, wordpress

pulling my hair out trying to change this

```
<nav class="mainnav ">
<a id="top"/>
<div class="navwrap">
<ul id="menu-top" class="menu">
<li id="menu-item-70" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu- item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-70">
<li id="menu-item-1603" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-has-children menu-item-1603">
```

I want to change it so the colour is always orange as a way to highlight the contact menu tab which is menu item 70

Comment: do you just want the menu-item-70 orange? the background? is it?

Comment: those are the worst class names I have ever seen

Comment: Please show what you have tried and what specifically goes wrong.

Comment: yes the background I would like constantly orange. I have tried .menu-item-71 {colour:orange}

Answer (score 0):

This assumes the anchor tag has no background styles applied.

```
.menu-item-71 {
background:#ff9900 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should already work if you put in your css file:

```
ul#menu-top.menu li#menu-item-70{
   background-color: #FFA62F;
}
```

Here there's a palette with more color codes:
http://www.computerhope.com/htmcolor.htm

You can also Use in-line styling as @Mastama says

```
<li id="menu-item-70" style="background-color:#FFA62F" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu- item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-70">
```